# How to make PayPal pull price of option? Opencart

Tags: php, paypal, opencart

We're using the built in Paypal Standard payment system on Opencart but it is not pulling the option price to Paypal.

Here is the code we have in our pp_standard.tpl file

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['model']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['price']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="weight_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['weight']; ?>" />
<?php $j = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option)  { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="on<?php echo $j; ?>_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $option['value']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="os<?php echo $j; ?>_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $option['price']; ?>" />
<?php $j++; ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I think the line that is the issue is this

```
<input type="hidden" name="os<?php echo $j; ?>_<?php echo $i; ?>"   
  value="<?php echo $option['price']; ?>" />
```

But I am not sure what to change it to for Paypal to pull the correct price

Here is the code that shows the price in the cart.tpl file

```
<?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
- <small><?php echo $option['name']; ?>: <?php echo $option['value']; ?>
- Price: <?php echo $option['price']; ?></small><br />
```